# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch Ruby on Rails using Device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I'm trying to complete sign up using gem `omniauth-google-oauth2, ~> 0.2.1` and `devise`

When I'm testing google sign up on local host I keep getting the following error:

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

What I have tried:

1) changing http into https

2) adding trailing '/' to URL in google auth panel

Both did not work for me.

I tried changing path in google auth panel but when I refresh the website path is the same as before.

[Changed path(https)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZa5D.png)

[Result(the same path as before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBkvp.png)

If you suggest to add some more details about the problem, feel free to comment the question.

Comment: didn't you forget `/users/` in the path?